# Calling AngularJS controller function from ios uiwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs

I have dashboard.html page and DashboardController.js is associated with dashboard.html. I am loading page in UIWebview and now I want to call a angularjs function from DashboardController.js from uiwebview. It does not get called.

Below is the code which I am trying in iOS

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);
    if (![Utility isInternetAvailable]) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DashboardController.test()"];
    NSString *response =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    return YES; // Return YES to make sure regular navigation works as expected.
}
```

I also tried without Controller reference after making sure that dashboard.html has been loaded inside uiwebview.
NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test()"];

While test() is js function inside my DashboardController.js scope.

```
function test (){
  alert('sendCredentialsToNativeApp');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you need DashboardController. ?? that's a function in my app - (void) sendJsonDataString:(NSString *)jsonData{
    
    // Création de la commance JS à envoyer.
    self.jsonActionToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sendData(%@);", jsonData];
    
    if (contentLoaded){
        NSLog(@"Contenu de la webView déjà chargé, le JS est executé.");
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:self.jsonActionToSend];
        self.jsonActionToSend = nil;
    }
}

Comment: The function that I am calling is remote DashboardController.js file that is linked with webpage that I am loading in uiwebview. So I want to call that function from objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test() method should be called if you have defined without controller reference in the controller JS. However, this will only be available after page readystate because you cannot call any method from the controller until its loaded completely.